# ASP.NET Application not starting - 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a simple c# asp.net website on IIS that contains:

```
Global.asax
Web.config
/bin
```

It worked fine when I access my route:

```
Mysite.com/api/test
```

We moved the files to another IIS server and I cant access my routes. Error 404 is shown.

Static files are served correctly.

Things we checked:

AppPool version is 4.0, AppPool in Integrated mode, Handler Mappings
are similar to the old server, IIS_IUSRS has all permissions to the folder.

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: 1) check if IIS asp.net + .net framework is enabled. 2) check application pool framework version.... etc.

Comment: Asp.net is enabled of course. Version is 4 integrated

Comment: *"of course"*: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: By simple asp.net website, what do you mean? If you are referring to MVC (which I'm guessing you are, since you mention routes), you need to make sure your Views folder gets copied out as well. Otherwise, your MVC controllers will not know where to locate your html.

Comment: This is not MVC. This is a standard webApi application. By "simple" I mean simple code without any special configirations etc..

Comment: You're going to have to show us the code for your routes and how you are trying to consume them.  There isnt enough info in this post to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like asp.net isn't installed on IIS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

aspnet_regiis -i

Answer (score 0):

Things to check before start your IIS:

POOL Permission
POOL Framework Version
Folder Permission - The folder where the aplication is hosted must have permission for the IIS_IUSRS user

After checking those itens your application should run or present another error message.

**Insert some printscreen to see the error.**

Comment: Checked all, they are fine :(

Comment: Try to enable debug mode and access the site from the server, it probably will show a differente error code like this format #08080008. After that update your post with printscreen of the iis error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the **WebAPIConfig** class exists in your App_Start folder. It should look something similar to this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Then check that this class is registered in your **Global.asax** class. There should be an entry like this one:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

which should be above this line:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```